# How inline keyboard starts conversation handler, when ended edit existing message with inline keyboard

Tags: python-telegram-bot

This is the code, a message is displayed with 3 vaiables that will be filled with the buttons, except for Hostname, that button will call a Conversation Handler in order to specify the hostname.

```
def custom_search_ask(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text(
                          text=f"Please configure the custom search:\nTime: {ctimechoosen}\nHostname: {chostnamechoosen}\nSeverity: {cseveritychoosen}",
                          reply_markup=custom_search_keyboard())
```

This is the keyboard with the options

```
def custom_search_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Time', callback_data='time_menu')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Hostname', callback_data='hostname_search')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Severity', callback_data='severity_menu')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Return back', callback_data='main')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
```

The button that calls the conversation handler

```
def hostname_ask(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    #query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data} \nPlease specify hostname:")
    return HOSTNAME
```

Conversation handler:

```
entry_points= [
      CallbackQueryHandler(hostname_ask, pattern='^hostname_search$')
      ]
    
    states = {
        HOSTNAME: [
            MessageHandler(filters = Filters.all , callback = custom_search_hostname_choosen)
        ],
```

Edit message and anwser with the introduced user data with new inline keyboard

```
def custom_search_hostname_choosen(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    
    message = update.effective_message
    message.edit_text(
                        text=f"Hostname specified \nTime: {ctimechoosen}\nHostname: {chostnamechoosen}\nSeverity: {cseveritychoosen}\nConfigure other presets or search?",
                        reply_markup=search_yes_no())
```

Really thanks for the help.

```
C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\ext\conversationhandler.py:287: UserWarning: If 'per_message=False', 'CallbackQueryHandler' will not be tracked for every message.
  warnings.warn(
2022-05-17 13:23:56,330 - apscheduler.scheduler - INFO - Scheduler started
User ID: 873363421 with name Ferzprox inicialized the BOT with /START
2022-05-17 13:24:07,808 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 555, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\ext\conversationhandler.py", line 626, in handle_update
    new_state = handler.handle_update(update, dispatcher, check_result, context)
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py", line 198, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "c:\Users\javie\Documents\Bot Telegram\Prod\Clean\menus.py", line 189, in custom_search_hostname_choosen
    message.edit_text(
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\message.py", line 2015, in edit_text
    return self.bot.edit_message_text(
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 130, in decorator
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 2775, in edit_message_text
    return self._message(
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\ext\extbot.py", line 200, in _message
    result = super()._message(
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 336, in _message
    result = self._post(endpoint, data, timeout=timeout, api_kwargs=api_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 295, in _post
    return self.request.post(
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 361, in post
    result = self._request_wrapper(
  File "C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 279, in _request_wrapper      
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Message can't be edited
```

Comment: Also I'm looking to avoid using global vars, I'm checking context.user_data :)

Answer (score 0):

In `custom_search_hostname_choosen`, the variable `query` will be an object of type [`Message`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a0/telegram.message.html#telegram-message) - because `update` is of type [`Update`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a0/telegram.update.html) and the attribute [`update.effective_message`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a0/telegram.update.html#telegram.Update.effective_message) is a `Message`.
the class `Message` does not have a method `edit_message_text`. It does however have a method [`Message.edit_text`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a0/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.edit_text). So you should change `query.edit_message_text` to `query.edit_text`. I also recommend to rename `query` to e.g. `message` to give it a more meaningful name.

Comment: I changed to message.edit_text as specified and i'm getting this now ```line 189, in custom_search_hostname_choosen
    message.edit_text(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'edit_text'```

Comment: what's the full traceback?

Comment: I added at the end of the post, too many characters. Thanks again

Comment: the traceback doesn't match your code. Please make sure that you have `message = update.effective_message` and not `message = update.effective_message.text`

Comment: my mistake again... I updated the code but now gives a: Message can't be edited. Full traceback at the end of the post

Comment: Right, I missed that. `update.effective_message` is the *incoming* message that the user sent. a bot can't edit the users message. However it's unclear to me wich message you want to edit.

Comment: I want to edit the message from def_hostmame_ask -> ```query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data} \nPlease specify hostname:")``` so when I call the conversation handler and i anwser, that message is changed by the anwser

Comment: Then you need to store a reference to that message or at least the corresponding `message_id` and `chat_id`. You can do that with the "storing data" wiki page that I pointed you to in the telegram group.